# Platform-spedific code (`Sys.setlocale()`) in a package vignette in R

Tags: r, cross-platform, r-package, cran

I have plaftform-spedific code in my package vignette:

```r
x <- c("01JAN2020:00:00:00", "15JAN2020:00:00:00")
# This is plaftform-spedific
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
# [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-15"
```

The vignette passes `R CMD check --as-cran` on my Windows machine, but would fail on a Linux machine (would need `locale = "en_US"`).

Is there good practice here? Would it work if I submit my package to CRAN as is? (checks seem to be run on different platforms on CRAN according to https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_summary.html)

Comment: Can't you just use `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`?

Comment: @Roland Yes, it works in this case (because the dates in `x` are in English). Can you can turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you can have platform-specific sources for vignettes. However, I would say that you usually don't need that.

In your example, I can only see a need to have anything platform-specific if the purpose is to show the user how to do it in a platform-specific way.

If that's the case, show how to do it on all platforms but don't evaluate the code. Then create the result in a platform-agnostic approach (maybe using `dput` output).

Else, just use a platform-agnostic approach, such as having the character strings in standard `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format. In your example `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` might also be a useful approach.

Comment: Thank you! Since I am not the producer of the data, I cannot change the format. I used locale = "C". From `?Sys.setlocale`, '"C" (...) is the default for the C language and reflects North-American usage – also known as "POSIX"'